# How to kill Cocos2d-x test app

Tags: android, c++, testing, integration-testing, cocos2d-x

We are creating an SDK that is used in Cocos2d-x games (on Android/iOS).

As part of development, we have setup a test framework for running various tests on a real device (Android only at the moment).

One specific test needs to kill the app and launch it again.

It seems that Cocos2d-x does not provide any API for exiting (or killing) the running app.

Some online resources suggested that people have used the call to `exit(0)`.

Is there any way to exit the game from Cocos2d-x ?

Calling `exit(0)` seems to crash:

```
#00  pc 0001e824  /system/lib/libc.so
#01  pc 0001c76c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#02  pc 000122ed  /system/lib/libc.so
#03  pc 00010f9d  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1184)
#04  pc 0000dabf  /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
#05  pc 000cbf59  /data/app-lib/com.test.cocos2dx_testapp-1/libhellocpp.so (cocos2d::BitmapDC::~BitmapDC()+10)
#06  pc 00024639  /system/lib/libc.so (__cxa_finalize+156)
#07  pc 000248f1  /system/lib/libc.so (exit+6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample project HelloCpp has an exit button in its example.  Look at HelloWorldScene.cpp and at the function call back menuCloseCallback (function might vary a bit based on version of cocos2dx you are on)

```
void HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback(CCObject* pSender)
{
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WINRT) || (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WP8)
    CCMessageBox("You pressed the close button. Windows Store Apps do not implement a close button.","Alert");
#else
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->end();
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_IOS)
    exit(0);
#endif
#endif
}
```

For android the answer would be CCDirector::sharedDirector()->end();

Note that I don't think Apple will approve you if your app calls exit(0).